# Disable Run Pipeline Button in Azure Yaml Pipeline file based on parameter conditions

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am using a pipeline parameter called “envName” in the yaml code below where the values have to be in the drop down while triggering the pipeline by the user.

```
    parameters:
    - name: envName
      displayName: >
        Select ENV from the list below
    type: string
    default: ' '
    values:
    - ' '
    - training
    - development
    - Quality
    - preproduction
    - production
```

My requirement is to disable the RUN button in pipeline when user selects empty dropdown value.Kindly provide a way to achieve this.Thanks in advance!

1. Tried to add the below condition after parameters section in yaml file.But it is ending up with errors.

   ```
   condition: ne(parameters.envName, ' ')
   ```
2. Added the condition at the variables section as below

   ```
   variables:
   - name: myEnv
     value: ${{parameters.envName}}
     condition: ne(variables. myEnv, ' ')
   ```

[PLEASE REFER TO THIS SCREENSHOT BELOW FOR CLEAR UNDERSTANDING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vyLv.png)